# How custom permissions are used to restrict sending and receiving the broadcasts within a single app?

Tags: android, permissions

I am learning from "Learning Android" - Oreilly - Marko Gargenta.

I am at chapter 11 (Broadcast Receivers)

I followed the book and everything work OK. But I have a question about how custom permissions are used to restrict sending and receiving the broadcasts within a single app.

The book is clear about this topic. but I feel there is something missing.

How do the receiver and the sender tell each other about different permissions?

In `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<permission
    android:name="saleh.yamba.SEND_TIMELINE_NOTIFICATIONS"
    android:description="@string/send_timeline_notifications_permission_description"
    android:label="@string/send_timeline_notifications_permission_label"
    android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.PERSONAL_INFO"
    android:protectionLevel="normal" />
<permission
    android:name="saleh.yamba.RECEIVE_TIMELINE_NOTIFICATIONS"
    android:description="@string/receive_timeline_notifications_permission_description"
    android:label="@string/receive_timeline_notifications_permission_label"
    android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.PERSONAL_INFO"
    android:protectionLevel="normal" />

<uses-permission android:name="saleh.yamba.SEND_TIMELINE_NOTIFICATIONS" />
<uses-permission android:name="saleh.yamba.RECEIVE_TIMELINE_NOTIFICATIONS" />
```

In the Service that send broadcasts:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("saleh.yamba.NEW_STATUS");
updaterService.sendBroadcast(intent, "saleh.yamba.RECEIVE_TIMELINE_NOTIFICATIONS");
```

Here, sender sends intent with `saleh.yamba.RECEIVE_TIMELINE_NOTIFICATIONS` permission, Ok,   How does the receiver know about this permission?

In the Activity that receives the broadcast via `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
   TimelineReceiver receiver;
   IntentFilter filter;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
   receiver = new TimelineReceiver();
   filter = new IntentFilter("saleh.yamba.NEW_STATUS");
}

protected void onResume()
{
   this.registerReceiver(receiver, filter, "saleh.yamba.SEND_TIMELINE_NOTIFICATIONS", null);
}

protected void onPause()
{
   this.unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}

   private class TimelineReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
   {
      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
      {
         //do something. 
      }
   }
```

Here receiver receives it with another permission. OK,
How does the receiver know about `saleh.yamba.RECEIVE_TIMELINE_NOTIFICATIONS`.
There is nothing in the code of the receiver part that tells that the `BroadcastReceiver` will be invoked only if the receiver has `saleh.yamba.RECEIVE_TIMELINE_NOTIFICATIONS`permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There is nothing in the code of the receiver part that tells that the BroadcastReceiver will be invoked only if the sender has saleh.yamba.RECEIVE_TIMELINE_NOTIFICATIONSpermission.

Yes, there is. You passed in `saleh.yamba.RECEIVE_TIMELINE_NOTIFICATIONS` to `registerReceiver()`.

Specifically, you are using [the four-parameter version of `registerReceiver()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#registerReceiver%28android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.content.IntentFilter,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Handler%29), where the third parameter is a "String naming a permissions that a broadcaster must hold in order to send an Intent to you. If null, no permission is required."

Comment: But I passed to `registerReceiver()` `saleh.yamba.SEND_TIMELINE_NOTIFICATIONS` Not `saleh.yamba.RECEIVE_TIMELINE_NOTIFICATIONS`, As the book says. Is it a book mistake?

Comment: @SalehFeek: Ah, OK, I see what you mean. It would appear that those permissions should be synchronized, and I do not know why they are not. You might try asking in the support forum for the book itself: http://marakana.com/forums/android/learning_android_book/